# Regex with multiple match in a string

Tags: php, regex

I would like some assistance to write the following Regex using this text input cause all my attempts failed.

```
$sample = "<p><span style=\"color:#4a4a4a;\"><span style=\"color:#4a5a6a;\"> Some others texts"
```

I would like to remove in the string all occurences of

```
<span style=\"color:#XXXXXX;\">
```

But the color being dynamic I have to catch it using a regex.

So I would like a regex which from that samples gives me the following matches :

```
<span style=\"color:#4a4a4a;\">
<span style=\"color:#4a5a6a;\">


$matches = array();
$regex = ????
preg_match($regex,$sample,$matches);
```

Can't find the good way of doing this.

EDIT :

My best attemp is :

`(.*?<span style=\\\"color:.*?\">)`

But this isn't what I'm looking for cause it's also taking what is before and after the span.

For example my first match here would be

```
<p><span style=\"color:#4a4a4a;\">
```

when I just want

```
<span style=\"color:#4a4a4a;\">
```

Comment: what about things like `color: #fff;` or `color: pink;` or `color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);` - the thing about HTML is that it's not really regular, so regular expressions are *usually* a bad fit, an HTML parser would probably be a better bet...

Comment: @CD001 I'm getting these data from an export, so as they all have that format, but if you have a smarter way to handle both cases i take it aswell. Thanks.

Comment: Normally you'd chuck the HTML snippet at [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and/or [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), and remove the nodes you don't want... I'd _probably_ look at [DOMXPath::query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) for the selector - this is similar to what you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677257/php-using-domxpath-to-strip-tags-and-remove-nodes.

Comment: @CD001 Yeah normally...the issue is that I'm getting a dom html which isn't well formated himself...amazing isn't it...that's why going with the regex seems to be my only solution to make the format fine again.

Comment: I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68644034/14853083) in response to a similar question a few days ago. You might find it useful

Comment: Actually I think I have a workaround, using my actual regex, I might be able to remove all what is before the `<span` occurence to get what I want...but I'm sure thee is a way of doing it with a one shot regex.

Comment: *"the issue is that I'm getting a dom html which isn't well formated"* ... Abandon all hope, ye who enter here. OK ... that means there's a chance it could be even *less* regular then well formatted HTML :( Might it be worth trying to "fix" it first with something like [Tidy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) or [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) (though I'm not sure that's still being developed)..?

Comment: ... or you could literally strip all tags and then wrap whatever is left in `<p>` tags if that's the ultimate aim?

Comment: @CD001 Looks like `(<span style=\\\"color:.*?\">)` is doing exactly what I want actually...I will adapt later if I have further issues... indeed that could be even less regular than what I think...but...dev joys....working with others crap is basis ;D Thanks for your help

Comment: @Claims - hey, I didn't do much, just kept you company while you figured it out ;) As long as those `<span>` tags don't have additional attributes you should be OK - it's possibly not the most robust solution but it really does depend on where your HTML comes from in the first place.

Comment: @CD001Thanks anyway I appreciate all help, you did tried, it's always better than people downgrading issues without even reading them like if this was any helpfull.  The datas are  coming from an export script I have no hand and can't control...so I have to deal with these data no matter what^^ i'm just cleaning everything to print it properly in a real template later. At this point i'm just saving the data themselves without all these craps like some character are escaped...but not all of them etc etc...fun.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Final solution seems to be : `(<span style=\\\"color:.*?\">)`

I'm sure this will be helpfull even if the issue is down for some akward reasons.